# changing values in wchar_t* []

Tags: c++, char, wchar-t

I have this code:

```
char *charTable[] = { "test1", "test2", "test3" };
size_t originSize[] = { 6, 6, 6 };
wchar_t* textValues[3];
const size_t newsize = 100;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    wchar_t wcstring[newsize];
    size_t convertedChars = 0;
    mbstowcs_s(&convertedChars, wcstring, originSize[i], charTable[i], _TRUNCATE);
    wcscat_s(wcstring, L"");
    textValues[i] = wcstring;
}
```

and I want to put `"test1"`, `"test2"`, `"test3"` in `textValues` as `wchar_t*`, but after loop `textValues` contain `"test3"`, `"test3"`, `"test3"`.

Comment: `wcstring` goes out of scope after the loop, meaning `textValues[i]` is a dangling pointer (meaning it points to nothing valid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to initialize the destination pointer to something:

```
textValues[i] = new wchar_t[newsize];
```

Then, instead of assigning `textValues[i] = wcstring;` (which makes a shallow copy), use `wcscpy`:

```
wcscpy(textValues[i], wcstring);
```

Or use the safer `wcscpy_s`:

```
wcscpy_s(textValues[i], newsize, wcstring);
```

Finally, remember to `delete` the newly allocated memory when you're done with it:

```
delete [] textValues[i];
```

Full sample:

```
char *charTable[] = { "test1", "test2", "test3" };
size_t originSize[] = { 6, 6, 6 };
wchar_t* textValues[3];
const size_t newsize = 100;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    wchar_t wcstring[newsize];
    size_t convertedChars = 0;
    mbstowcs_s(&convertedChars, wcstring, originSize[i], charTable[i], _TRUNCATE);
    wcscat_s(wcstring, L"");
    textValues[i] = new wchar_t[newsize];
    wcscpy_s(textValues[i], newsize, wcstring);
}

//later
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    delete [] textValues[i];
}
```